# What is required to display custom messages in jenkins report?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xunit.net

I have Jenkins ver. 2.7.4 and I want to see custom messages in report 
besides stack trace. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing a jenkins plugin and you've subclassed [`Notifier`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/Notifier.html), then you can log to the build output using an instance of [`BuildListener`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/BuildListener.html), like so:

Helper method:

```
private void logger(BuildListener listener, String message){
    listener.getLogger().println(message);
}
```

Example Usage:

```
logger(listener, "Verbose Logging Enabled");
```

You can see a real world example of this in the [source code for the packagecloud plugin for jenkins](https://github.com/computology/packagecloud-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/packagecloud/ArtifactPublisher.java#L152-L160)

See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Packagecloud+Plugin

Comment: I'm using xUnit plugin fot jenkins and I don't want to write custom plugin. I am writting tests on C# and I can write some messages and they will appear in xml report but will not appear in jenkins report. See : https://monosnap.com/file/NSN5mVgUW0ssy3fffwJSwxsvHAMhzC https://monosnap.com/file/evaYiBkaKfg3YQ2oHH56qnjqWJmRVk. I want that "Comment" appears in jenkins report